# token substitution (resource filtering) with sbt

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

I am looking in SBT for the same functionality Maven has for resource filtering, but does not come out of the box.

After searching quite a bit both here and elsewhere, i found two plugins close in functionality, but neither one really does it. For example, [xsbt-filter](https://github.com/sdb/xsbt-filter) does not filter tokens such as `${baseDirectory}`, while sbt-editsource does not work in conjunction with unit nor integration testing (see [issue 9](https://github.com/bmc/sbt-editsource/issues/9))

So, i tried to code that myself by modifying one of those two plugins, but here is the question i was not able to figure out in SBT, being new to it (and not a Scala pro):

*How do you reuse SBT build settings for doing token resolution?*

Those settings are in object `sbt.Keys`. So for example, `baseDirectory` is:

```
val baseDirectory = SettingKey[File]("base-directory")
```

There are dozens of them (perhaps hundreds) that can be used for resolving tokens in a resource file.

In the end, for doing token resolution within the plugin code, you need a map `Map[String, String]` of all build settings present in Keys, i.e. key is "baseDirectory" and the value is whatever at compile time that value is.

I assume one way would be to use reflection, but before going down that path, i thought i asked if there was a more standard way of doing this from an sbt plugin, which seems fairly basic.

All plugins i have seen so far, are copying and pasting each Keys setting (transforming the variable name into a string for the key) into their plugin code.

---

For those unfamiliar with resource filtering, it means that the build tool should be able to resolve all tokens present in a resource file and at compile time place the resource file under target after substituting the token key with its value (example: resource file is "`/User/me/Documents/myproject/src/test/resources/myfile.txt`", in which text has a string `${target}`, where "`target`" is the key and "`/User/me/Documents/myproject/target`" happens to be its value in that specific build).

Answer (score 2):

> In the end, for doing token resolution within the plugin code, you need a map Map[String, String] of all build settings present in Keys, i.e. key is "baseDirectory" and the value is whatever at compile time that value is.

sbt internally holds on to these information, so you can query them.
For example, there's a command in sbt called `inspect` that tells you the current value for the setting, and all other dependency that it uses. A while back I wrote a plugin that calls it recursively and prints it out in ASCII art tree, called sbt-inspectr: https://github.com/eed3si9n/sbt-inspectr.

There's also `Project.runTask(...)`, which you might need.